# Business Data Connectivity entity namespace purpose

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, bdc, bdc-model, custom-bdc

I've noticed that my BDC's entity namespace is a SharePoint website url.

I have recently imported successfully our BDC during a SharePoint migration, and the namespace remains the same on the new farm.

The question is : what happens if the webapp the entity namespace is referring to is shut down ?

Is the BDC just an simple identifier, or is it needed for connection reasons ?

Thank you guys.